# how to display column name in hive

Tags: hive

i have  a  table of 3  numeric fields var1,var2,var3 and I  need to find  the minimum out of the  3 and also store the name of the column with the least value in a  new  column name

for example

| var1 | var2 | var3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 5 | 6 | 3 |
| -2 | 1 | 0 |

Result should be :

| field1 | field2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | var1 |
| 3 | var3 |
| -2 | var1 |

My question is  how do I  create field2  in Hive?
Any  suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `least()`.

```
select least(var1,var2,var3) as field1,
case 
when least(var1,var2,var3)=var1 then 'var1'
when least(var1,var2,var3)=var2 then 'var2'
else 'var3'
end as field2
From mytable
```

Had to hardcode the column name. If you have manageable number of columns, you can use this approach. But if you have 100s of columns, then its not feasible.

Comment: right ,right. Did not think of this,  Thanks a  lot :)

Comment: Glad it helped :)